# redirect input audio to output with USB sound card

Tags: audio, alsa

I am using rpi for airplay with same speaker that I use for my pc. So I don't want to deal with cables everytime when I pass to rpi from pc. Can I connect audio output of pc to input of rpi and get all the output (both pc and airplay) from rpi without any latency? I am using usb soundcard for the input and output.

I have looked how to redirect sound with using alsa but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It's not possible to do anything without latency. That's simple physics.  How much latency is tolerable?

Comment: as long as human hear doesn't recognize latency at videos and games it is okay. So i think it shoul be below 100 miliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Simpler fix:

**Buy a 3.5mm audio jack splitter**

Like the one [here](http://www.zzounds.com/item--HOSYMP234?siid=121855&-vBRDlsM7utpaJ47ABEiQAIpKjTEYYGODM1Vj9A1NZux5hEswbo5iKqQghlqVGfkLzVtAaAtHF8P8HAQ=) or [here](http://www.miniinthebox.com/3-5mm-audio-splitter-1-female-to-2-male-3-5mm-jack-splitter-converter-adapter_p3381693.html).